# Нужны ли кавычки? (3)

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

`Он первый («)первый(»), а ты второй («)первый(»).`

Answer (score 0):

***Первый 1-й, и второй 1-й.***

Если один и другой достигли одного уровня (в спорте это ничьи, парные виды) результата, фраза, фиксирующая такой случай, станет понятна вполне, когда избавится от повторных слов. Во избежании лишних вопросов уместно использовать порядковые числительные. Без них можно обойтись там, где речь, к примеру, идёт о качестве (*Кажется, что самый трудный первый и второй*).